# Implement autocomplete (jquery-ui & PHP) with multiple input fields having same name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have multiple input fields with same name

```
<input type="text" name="pname" />
<input type="text" name="pname" />
```

I'm generating these input fields by cloning the first one using jquery. Therefore there can be 'x' number of input fields.

I'm also implementing autocomplete function by targeting the 'name' attribute.

```
$('[name="pname"]').each(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: "searchproduct.php",
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

The autocomplete works fine for first input field. But from next input field I get same result as first one i.e I'm not shown a list of matching results but the result from the first input field only.

How to get different result in each input field?

Comment: use a class instead of a name

Comment: @Syahrul Nope.It didn't work.

Comment: working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/1090/). can you reproduce the issue by taking the data returned by `searchproduct.php`  into a local variable like i did in fiddle.